# User's print file status - monitored in java

Tags: java, file, printing

I am trying to monitor the progress of a document that is printing to file. ( The print is given to a physical printer but it is saved to file )

How would I use print job event in this scenario ?

I have tried

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class DetermineThatPrintJobHasFinished {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Open the image file

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.pdf"));

        // create a PDF doc flavor

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;

        // Locate the default print service for this environment.

        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        // Create and return a PrintJob capable of handling data from

        // any of the supported document flavors.

        DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();

        // register a listener to get notified when the job is complete

        JobCompleteMonitor monitor = new JobCompleteMonitor();

        printJob.addPrintJobListener(monitor);

        // Construct a SimpleDoc with the specified 

        // print data, doc flavor and doc attribute set.

        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

        // Print a document with the specified job attributes.

        printJob.print(doc, null);

        monitor.waitForJobCompletion();

        is.close();

    }

    private static class JobCompleteMonitor extends PrintJobAdapter {

        private boolean completed = false;

        @Override
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        private void signalCompletion() {

            synchronized (JobCompleteMonitor.this) {

                completed = true;

                JobCompleteMonitor.this.notify();

            } 

        }

        public synchronized void waitForJobCompletion() {

            try {

                while (!completed) {

                    wait();

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

    }

}
```

but that seems to print a file from the program and monitor it. 
My requirement doesn't want a java program to print. Instead, monitor the print ->( save to file). So, I was not sure how would I pass this event as a parameter ?
To be simple the below line of code is what I am more interested in modifying and finding out a way.

```
// Create and return a PrintJob capable of handling data from

// any of the supported document flavors.

DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: `wait` + `notify` is much simpler and safer if you replace it with a `new CountDownLatch(1)`, then `countDown()` instead of `notify` and `await` instead of `wait`.

Comment: Sure. But passing the user action as a printjob is what I am more looking to modify. The program above initiates a print job of its own. I want to send the existing print as a parameter instead. How would I achieve that ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I just don't like wait / notify :)

Comment: Not a problem. But thanks for sharing countDown().